# Trying to match strings when importing a CSV with Powershell

Tags: powershell, csv

I am trying to create a report showing older operating systems out of a CSV file. The program displays the output beautifully, but doesn't actually parse anything. I'm trying to separate out Windows 2000, 2003, XP, and yes, windows NT machines. The sample data is below:

```
Finding Title,IP Address / FQDN,Port,Service,OS,FQDN,Default Username,Default Password,Remediation Notes,Misc Notes,Misc Notes 2,Contact,Remediation
Default Password (yada) for 'yadayada' Account on Windows,fakefake,445,cifs,Microsoft Windows Server 2003 Service Pack 2,fakefake,yadayada,yadayada,Change the password.,,,,
Default Password (yadayada) for 'yadayada' Account on Windows,fakefake1,445,cifs,Microsoft Windows Server 2003 Service Pack 2,fakefake1,yadayada,yadayada,Change the password.,,,,
Default Password (yadayada) for 'yadayada' Account on Windows,fakefake2,445,cifs,Microsoft Windows Server 2003 Service Pack 1,fakefake2,yadayada,yadayada,Change the password.,,,,
Default Password (yadayada) for 'yadayada' Account on Windows,fakefake3,445,cifs,Microsoft Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard,fakefake3,yadayada,yadayada,Change the password.
```

The program I have so far is here:

```
$name = Read-Host 'CSV File?'
$csvs = import-csv $name
$object = $csvs.os


ForEach ( $object in $csvs ) {

if ($object -like '*2003*') { out-file  -inputobject $object  -append $name}
elseif ($object -like '*2000*') { out-file  -inputobject $object  -append $name}
elseif ($objects -clike '*NT*') { out-file  -inputobject $object  -append $name}
elseif ($object -clike '*XP*') { out-file  -inputobject $object  -append $name}
write-output $outfile
}
$a = "<style>"
$a = $a + "BODY{background-color:white;}"
$a = $a + "TABLE{border-width: 1px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;border-collapse: collapse;}"
$a = $a + "TH{border-width: 1px;padding: 2px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;background-color:thistle}"
$a = $a + "TD{border-width: 1px;padding: 2px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;background-color:white}"
$a = $a + "TD:Nth-Child(Odd) {Background-Color: #dddddd;}"
$a = $a + "</style>"


import-csv $name | ConvertTo-HTML -head $a| Out-File C:\Users\myuser\Downloads\scripts\Test.htm
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have a bug in there, you have 2 variables named object that you are using for different purposes:

```
$object = $csvs.os

ForEach ( $object in $csvs ) # object above getting overwritten
```

I would just get rid of the first object assignment and write the loop like this:

```
ForEach ( $object in $csvs ) {

if ($object.os -like '*2003*') { out-file  -inputobject $object  -append $name}
elseif ($object.os -like '*2000*') { out-file  -inputobject $object  -append $name}
elseif ($object.os -clike '*NT*') { out-file  -inputobject $object  -append $name}
elseif ($object.os -clike '*XP*') { out-file  -inputobject $object  -append $name}
}
```

Though you can avoid the repetition like this:

```
$csvs | where-object{ $_.os -like '*2003*' -or $_.os -like '*2000*' -or $_.os -clike '*NT*' -or $_.os -clike '*XP*'} |  out-file -append $name
```

Comment: I tried both of those but I still get the windows 2008 result in the end html file? Or did i miss something? I replaced the For loop with both answers and got rid of the first assignment.